# Sanity Serializers in Eleventy (11ty)

Tags: sanity, eleventy

I've implemented Sanity CMS into Eleventy, and have a working 11ty filter that converts Portable Text to HTML.

I have a fair number of custom blocks, and therefore I'm also passing serializers. However, I am incapable of making one of those serializers work.

Here is my code:

**On .eleventy.js**

```
    // Portable Text to HTML Filter for Sanity
eleventyConfig.addFilter('sanityToHTML', function(value) {
    return blocksToHtml({
      blocks: value,
      serializers: serializers
    })
  })
```

**On serializers.js**

```
const { h } = require("@sanity/block-content-to-html");

module.exports = {
  types: {
      cta: ({ node }) => {
        return h(
          'a',
          {
            className:
              'bg-yellow-500 text-white',
            href: node.ctaUrl,
          },
          node.ctaText,
        )
      },
      infoText: ({ node }) => {
        return h(
          'p',
          {
            className:
              'bg-blue-500 text-white',
          },
          node.bodyInfo.map(children => children.text).join(''),
        )
      },
    },
  }
```

Eleventy is oputputting the `<p class="bg-blue-500 text-white"></p>` , but without content.

I've tried all combinations that I can think of.

My Sanity blog post has the following structure:

```
{
  "_createdAt": "2021-09-14T11:25:05Z",
  "_id": "89ff5403-326b-4db1-8752-04ea1c85f114",
  "_rev": "7dkOKJtWoyCn0kHUhHzZu7",
  "_type": "post",
  "_updatedAt": "2021-09-20T06:38:14Z",
  "body": [
    {
      "_key": "f84e932860bf",
      "_type": "block",
      "children": [
        {
          "_key": "bd29bce1dda1",
          "_type": "span",
          "marks": [],
          "text": ""
        }
      ],
      "markDefs": [
        {
          "_key": "38aa715c6214",
          "_type": "link",
          "href": "........"
        }
      ],
      "style": "normal"
    },
    {
      "_key": "bf5d17f3da91",
      "_type": "cta",
      "ctaText": "test",
      "ctaUrl": ".........."
    },
    {
      "_key": "595873ddfc54",
      "_type": "block",
      "children": [
        {
          "_key": "ba794ddbef68",
          "_type": "span",
          "marks": [],
          "text": ""
        }
      ],
      "markDefs": [
        {
          "_key": "38aa715c6214",
          "_type": "link",
          "href": ".........."
        }
      ],
      "style": "normal"
    },
    {
      "_key": "8acb94638c0c",
      "_type": "infoText",
      "bodyInfo": [
        {
          "_key": "6b6e533e67fd",
          "_type": "block",
          "children": [
            {
              "_key": "3593ad3abdf9",
              "_type": "span",
              "marks": [],
              "text": "test test info"
            }
          ],
          "markDefs": [],
          "style": "normal"
        }
      ]
    },
    .....etc
```

Any tips on how to make it display the actual content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is in your `infoText` serializer. In that function, you're mapping over `node.bodyInfo` and then accessing the `text` property on the objects in `bodyInfo`. However, the objects in `bodyInfo` do not actually have a `text` property.

```json
{
  "_key": "8acb94638c0c",
  "_type": "infoText",
  "bodyInfo": [
    {
      "_key": "6b6e533e67fd",
      "_type": "block",
      "children": [
        {
          "_key": "3593ad3abdf9",
          "_type": "span",
          "marks": [],
          "text": "test test info"
        }
      ],
      "markDefs": [],
      "style": "normal"
    }
  ]
}
```

The string you are trying to extract is at `bodyInfo[].children[].text`, not `bodyInfo[].text`. To fix this, you might want to update your `infoText` serializer.

```js
infoText: ({ node }) => {
  return h(
    'p',
    {
      className: 'bg-blue-500 text-white',
    },
    node.bodyInfo.map(({children}) => children.map(child => child.text)).flat().join(''),
  )
}
```

In this version, we first map over `bodyInfo`, which is an array, then destructure the `children` property from the objects within. We then map over that to get our inner strings, then flatten the array to join.